# Using Storm in Cloudera

Tags: cloudera, apache-storm

I have been looking to use Storm which is available with Hortonworks 2.1 installation but in order to avoid installing Hortonworks in addition to a Cloudera installation (which has Spark in it), I tried to find a way to use Storm in Cloudera.

If one can use both Storm and Spark on a single platform then it will save additional resources required to have both Cloudera and Hortonworks installations on a machine.

Comment: why is this tagged with apache-spark?

Comment: Fixed that. This is a strangely formatted question.

Comment: ok, you are should not have tagged into SPARK. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use storm with Cloudera installation.  You will have to install it on your own and maintain it as such.  It will not be part of the Cloudera stack but that should not stop you from using it along with Hadoop if you need it.

Comment: ok, great then are the overheads of installing STORM on cloudera so much that I shall instead go with Hortonworks to use STORM?

Comment: I can't really answer this question as its very subjective.  I don't think the overheads of installing and maintaining storm is a whole lot where you need to switch your vendor but if you feel that is the case then HW probably makes sense as they support both Hadoop and Storm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Storm on any of the vendor platform. However, storm cluster management is something you have to consider. Storm is not part of the CDH distribution. Cloudera Manager does not manage the lifecycle of the storm services and configurations, nor does it monitor the storm cluster, unless you are willing to write a Clouderea Manager extension yourself. On the contrary, if you choose a vendor such as HDP, the Ambari management tool on HDP provides all the above management features.

If you have a streaming project on CDH, you should strongly consider Apache Spark first, as it provides the same programming model for both batch and streaming processing. You do not need to learn a new API. However, Apache Spark streaming is micro-batch. Thus in use cases that requires sub-second low latency real-time processing, Storm is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Storm *alongside* Cloudera.

Answer (score 0):

All the above are true, but why would you?

Spark includes Spark Streaming, which allows you to handle data processing and stream/event processing workloads using a single API. Spark/Streaming is already inside CDH.

So, why burden yourself with two different APIs?

Comment: Storm is true streaming, whereas Spark is micro-batching. For some near real-time applications, the latency incurred by the micro-batches could have a financial impact.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Apache Storm on Cloudera VM. 
For a basic setup and test run, follow below link:

https://github.com/vrmorusu/StormOnClouderaVM/wiki/Apache-Storm-on-Cloudera-VM

This should get you started on developing Storm applications on Cloudera VM.